# Phoenix hub type-C 9 in 1 is not working properly

Tags: usb, hdmi, usb-c, dock, usb-hub

I recently bought the following product: http://www.phoenixtechnologies.es/?mod=ampliar&act=ficha&val=PHHUBTYPEC9IN1 with the following connections:

[image]

I have just connected it to a Windows PC and:

- USB keyboard works.
- USB mouse works.
- HDMI does not work in Windows, but it does in MacOS.

I have updated the drivers (though I have not found any official drivers on the manufacturer page) and updated Windows to its latest version. In addition the following error appears in Windows:

```
Unknown USB device (link in compliance mode)
```

After some time this what Device Status says:

```
Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)

A USB port reset request failed.
```

More details about device status:

[image]

Do you have any idea why it's not working?

Note: the monitor actually does something, even though it is not detected in Windows. My monitor info says it is connected but no image appears. I have also tried `ctrl`+`Windows`+`shift`+`B`, but it does not work.

Comment: The device in question does not support daisy-chaining video (through USB 3.0 Type-C).  That is a feature of Thunderbolt.

Comment: And what about the problem with the HDMI port in windows? And the 'Unknowm USB device'?

Comment: Honestly; I suspect the device is using a substandard USB chipset.  Doesn’t help my web security indicated the website is known for malicious payloads (that doesn’t mean it’s not legitimate, just that I won’t visit it, since trust the software)

Comment: Hum, but it's strange it works in my Mac but not in my windows... I did not know that about the page, I bought the dock in a physical shop this morning.

Comment: I have added more details related to the HDMI connector not working in Windows, in case you know something.